# New QGIS install not finding GISBASE?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation

At QGIS startup I get the message: "QGIS couldn't find your GRASS installation.
Would you like to specify path (GISBASE) to your GRASS installation?" (Windows 7) No amount of rooting around the directory structure in the GRASS directories solves it.  Tried uninstalling/reinstalling, no joy, but I also noticed that my plugins were still there, so the uninstall does not appear to have been fully clean.

I have a perfectly working installation on another Windows 7 machine that I installed just last week, so no clue why there's a problem on this machine.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you can create it manually (create the folder) and when you start the grass-plugin just select it as follows in the screenshot by using the browse-button:
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  So the plugin works, but the error message still persists.

Comment: @Steve Bernstein: sorry to hear, that the message still pops up

Comment: @Steve Bernstein: take a look at: c:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\GRASS6 there should be something like this:GISDBASE: C:\Users\Kurt\Documents\GIS DataBase\China
LOCATION_NAME: Austria-Projekt-Location
MAPSET: PERMANENT
GRASS_GUI: wxpython

Answer (score 0):

This worked: Uninstalled, cleaned the registry (w/CCleaner), deleted residual folders.  Reinstalled with the OSgeo4W Windows installer instead of the QGIS Windows installer, all good.

Oddly, all my plugins are still installed, so it appears despite believing I'd taken every step I know to truly uninstall, there were artifacts of the previous install.  I think that ought not be.

Comment: did you also look at c:\users\YourUsername\.qgis here are the plugins stored for the user called YourUsername

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall, and reinstall into  C:\Program Files\QGISValmiera (without a space between QGIS and Valmiera) and it works.

The windows installer is not putting double quotes around path names which contain special characters like spaces.  You can see this in your install log at:  C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera postinstall.log.  I have submitted a bug report.

Solution first came from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87477/qgis-gisbase-specify-location)