# Specifying GISBASE location for QGIS install?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation

I am just a beginner at this QGIS and GRASS and I am using this QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour which
 throws a error at the startup that

> "**QGIS couldn't find your GRASS installation. Would you like to
>   specify path (GISBASE) to your GRASS installation?**"

I cannot find the root cause of the problem or any way to solve it.

> From other forum posts, I can see that many others have seen this
>   problem but no one has given a clear cut solution to it.

If someone can help me with this issue, it will be really helpful. My project work is at halt, so please help me solve it.

**The installer is **

> QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.0.1-3-Setup-x86

and

> WinGRASS-6.4.3-1-Setup

Also one more update is that it runs fine on my laptop which intel i7 and 4GB RAM with Windows 8
but not on my desktop which is an INTEL DUAL CORE and 2GB RAM which has Windows 7 Enterprise

---

*my "postinstall.log"* **FILE**:

```
`C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\postinstall.log
OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour
OSGEO4W_STARTMENU=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour
OSGEO4W_ROOT_MSYS=/C/PROGRA~1/QGIS Dufour

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour"\bin\make-bat-for-py.bat

    Generating .bat files for all .py files in C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>set ICON=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>set ICON_CMD=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_cmd.ico 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>set ICON_TCLTK=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_tcltk.ico 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>set BATCH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\grass64.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour"\bin\grass64.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour"\bin\grass64 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\fontcap 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\GRASS GIS 6.4.3"  

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\GRASS GIS 6.4.3\GRASS 6.4.3 GUI.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\grass64.bat" "-wx" \ "Launch GRASS GIS 6.4.3 with wxGUI" 1 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico"  

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\GRASS GIS 6.4.3\GRASS 6.4.3 GUI.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\grass64.bat
Arguments;         -wx
Working Directory: \
Description:       Launch GRASS GIS 6.4.3 with wxGUI
Display Mode:      Normal Window (1)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\GRASS GIS 6.4.3\GRASS 6.4.3 Old TclTk GUI.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\grass64.bat" "-tcltk" \ "Launch GRASS GIS 6.4.3 with the old TclTk GUI" 1 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_tcltk.ico"  

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\GRASS GIS 6.4.3\GRASS 6.4.3 Old TclTk GUI.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\grass64.bat
Arguments;         -tcltk
Working Directory: \
Description:       Launch GRASS GIS 6.4.3 with the old TclTk GUI
Display Mode:      Normal Window (1)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_tcltk.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\GRASS GIS 6.4.3\GRASS 6.4.3 Command Line.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\grass64.bat" "-text" \ "Launch GRASS GIS 6.4.3 in text mode" 1 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_cmd.ico"  

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\GRASS GIS 6.4.3\GRASS 6.4.3 Command Line.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\grass64.bat
Arguments;         -text
Working Directory: \
Description:       Launch GRASS GIS 6.4.3 in text mode
Display Mode:      Normal Window (1)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_cmd.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Desktop\GRASS GIS 6.4.3.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\grass64.bat" "-wx" \ "Launch GRASS GIS 6.4.3 with wxGUI" 1 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico"  

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Desktop\GRASS GIS 6.4.3.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\grass64.bat
Arguments;         -wx
Working Directory: \
Description:       Launch GRASS GIS 6.4.3 with wxGUI
Display Mode:      Normal Window (1)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>del "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour"\bin\grass64.bat.tmpl 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>del "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour"\bin\grass64.tmpl 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>for %f in ("C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp") do call set TEMPDRIVE=%~df 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>call set TEMPDRIVE=C: 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>cd C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp 

C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp>"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\vcredist_2005_x86.exe" /q /t:C: 

C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp>if errorlevel 3010 echo Dufour\etc\reboot 1>C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 

C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp>del "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\vcredist_2005_x86.exe" 

C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp>"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\vcredist_2008_x86.exe" /q 

C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp>if errorlevel 3010 echo Dufour\etc\reboot 1>C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 

C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp>del "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\vcredist_2008_x86.exe" 

C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp>"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\vcredist_2010_x86.exe" /q 

C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp>if errorlevel 3010 echo Dufour\etc\reboot 1>C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 

C:\Users\ab281182\AppData\Local\Temp>del "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\vcredist_2010_x86.exe" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour" 
A subdirectory or file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour already exists.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\MSYS Shell.lnk"       "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\msys\msys.bat" " " \ "Minimal SYStem" 7 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\msys\msys.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\MSYS Shell.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\msys\msys.bat
Arguments;          
Working Directory: \
Description:       Minimal SYStem
Display Mode:      Minimized  (7)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\msys\msys.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Desktop\MSYS Shell.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\msys\msys.bat" " " \ "Minimal SYStem" 7 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\msys\msys.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Desktop\MSYS Shell.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\msys\msys.bat
Arguments;          
Working Directory: \
Description:       Minimal SYStem
Display Mode:      Minimized  (7)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\msys\msys.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t apps/msys/etc/fstab 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>dllupdate -oite -copy -reboot "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\libeay32.dll" 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\libeay32.dll: Version=1.0.1.3
C:\Windows\system32\libeay32.dll: Version=0.0.0.0
Target does not exist, no action.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>dllupdate -oite -copy -reboot "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\ssleay32.dll" 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\ssleay32.dll: Version=1.0.1.3
C:\Windows\system32\ssleay32.dll: Version=0.0.0.0
Target does not exist, no action.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t bin\pyuic4.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS Dufour 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyqtconfig.py 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>call C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\make-bat-for-py.bat 
'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>call "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour"\bin\o4w_env.bat 

'"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
OSGEO4W home is C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour
Synchronizing CRS database with GDAL/PROJ definitions.
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
Loading epsg.wkt
0 WKTs loaded
CRS update (inserted:0 updated:0 deleted:3631 errors:0)
No CRS updates were necessary.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t bin\qgis.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t bin\qgis-browser.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>REM get short path without blanks 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>for %i in ("C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour") do set O4W_ROOT=%~fsi 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>set O4W_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour" 
A subdirectory or file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour already exists.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour" "QGIS Desktop 2.0.1" "exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\qgis.bat" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour" "QGIS Browser 2.0.1" "exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\qgis-browser.bat" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\nircmd.exe" "~$folder.desktop$" "QGIS Desktop 2.0.1" "exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\qgis.bat" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\nircmd.exe" "~$folder.desktop$" "QGIS Browser 2.0.1" "exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\qgis-browser.bat" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS Dufour 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\bin\qgis.reg" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>"C:\Windows\regedit" /s "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\bin\qgis.reg" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS Dufour 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t "C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS Dufour"\bin\qt.conf 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\Setup.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\setup.bat -R C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour" "" "" "Installer" 1 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\Setup.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\bin\setup.bat -R C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour
Arguments;         
Working Directory: 
Description:       Installer
Display Mode:      Normal Window (1)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t bin/setup.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t bin/setup-test.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour" 
A subdirectory or file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour already exists.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.bat" " " \ "OSGeo for Windows command shell" 1 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.bat
Arguments;          
Working Directory: \
Description:       OSGeo for Windows command shell
Display Mode:      Normal Window (1)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Desktop\OSGeo4W.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.bat" " " \ "OSGeo for Windows command shell" 1 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Desktop\OSGeo4W.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.bat
Arguments;          
Working Directory: \
Description:       OSGeo for Windows command shell
Display Mode:      Normal Window (1)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS Dufour 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Dufour>textreplace -std -t apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sipconfig.py 
`
```

So what do you think now?

---

Comment: Can you add which OS and which installer you used?

Comment: thanks for replying Andre Joost, I have edited my problem and now it includes the installer name and OS information

Comment: Also Andre I want to learn this using QGIS to an advanced level, so can you tell how shall I start with it. As of now, I just a beginner.

Comment: Learning by doing is a thing that can not be teached in an easy way.

Comment: A crumb for those to follow:  I am having this same issue on the newer version, QGIS Valmiera, on Windows 7 x64, installing WinGRASS-6.4.3-1-Setup.exe and QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.2.0-1-Setup-x86_64.exe.  Looks like there might be a solution below, but wanted to add another data point to help the next guy.

Comment: @Elipticalview Actually the folder name in the installation directory 'Program Files\QGISDufour' should match with the name in QGIS settings---> Environment variables ----> GISBASE & path.
So if there is now space between 'QGISDufour' in installation directory i.e. "Program Files", then it should match with the "GISBASE" & "path" environment variables in QGIS Settings.

Comment: @abhinavgoyal02, Thanks but I'm confused.  I don't see any settings->Environment.. in my menu, nor in my windows environment variables.  We must be running very different versions.  I see that Dufour is 2.0.  What I've got a the moment is 2.2.0-Valmiera for Windows.  But I'm open to suggestion, is Dufour better than Valmiera?  Also what OS are you running on.  Thanks.  And btw, I have been able to prove there is a bug in the windows version and have reported such for not having quotes around the path name and thereby gagging on the embedded space.

Comment: @Elipticalview The path in my Dufour 2.0 is SETTINGS----> OPTIONS----> SYSTEM Tab----> Under the heading 'Current Environment Variables'-----> GISBASE variable & PATH variable(Correction to previous path).
I hope this path is somewhat similar for you in Valmiera. If not so, please search a bit in your version. And then modify your folder name in the installation directory to match the way it is in your Settings.

Also I have never used Valmiera so I can't really say which one is better.
My OS is: WINDOWS 7
And you are right it is a bug and quite troublesome for new people.

Comment: I found what you were referring to finally, and thankfully all of my variables have been correctly set to ..QGISValmiera..  To be clear I changed the installation path to ..QGISValmiera.. from ..QGIS Valmiera.. when I installed.  So it looks like this workaround has got everything right.  Thanks you for looking at this.  Cheers!

Comment: @Elipticalview Its good I could get your problem solved. Could you also please vote up my comment to help others looking for this problem

Comment: @abhinavgoyal02, I had already upvoted it.  Please do me the favor of signing in to the bug report here and chiming with a request to get this fixed by adding quotes to long file names, and not by regressing back to 8.3 names, in:  http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows standalone installer you used has its own GRASS and does not require to install WINGRASS separately. It might be that those two interfere.

Uninstall WINGRASS and QGSIS, delete the .qgis2 path in your user folder, and reinstall QGIS only.

Then look into C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Dufour\postinstall.log for any error messages. When it complains that the PATH variablke exceeds 1024 characters, clean that.

Alternatively, you can use the OSGEO4W setup installer.

---

From your postinstall.log:

```
'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

is the point where it breaks. Strangely, it did work for me on the same operating system.
Try to install everything into `C:\QGISDufour\` to avoid any blanks in the pathname, or use osgeo4w-setup.exe, which installs into `C:\OSGEO4W\`

Comment: ok. Nice I did as you have said but still the problem persists and also i cannot find in the  C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Dufour\postinstall.log the error like PATH variable exceeds 1024 characters.

Comment: Are there any other error messages in the file?

Comment: Andre I have included a copy of my postinstall.log file, can you tell me if there is some error I should be worried about

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: yes, I tried your extended answer but even that is not working... I even tried on my friends desktop but it gives the same problem. Amazingly it works on my laptop!!!

What do you say?

Comment: The error messages in postinstall.log should not occur when installing to C:\QGISDufour\

Comment: Thank you so much Andre, It seems the problem has dissapeared last idea you said "postinstall.log should not occur when installing to C:\QGISDufour\ " i.e the directory name "QGISDufour" should not have any spaces was the Key.

The Windows Standalone Installer creates a default installation directory as "C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour" and as you said 'QGISDufour' should not have any spaces.

The GISBASE variable value also does not have that space there so, if the installation has it then the things do not match and we get stuck with a problem not easy to figure out for a new user(beginner).

Answer (score 2):

This problem is related to the deactivation of short names under windows. The short names compatibility is required for a large number of program. To reset the management of short names for access to the QGIS directory, open a box of MS/DOS dialog by running cmd.exe in administrator mode, on the root directory, execute the following two lines of commands:
C: > fsutil 8dot3name set 0
C: > fsutil file setshortname "Program Files" "PROGRA~1"
Dir / x command to check the short name for the folder "Program Files"

You can execute the same commands for the folder "QGIS Dufour" with the short name "QGISDU~1", or you can reinstall qgis because the command "fsutil 8dot3name set 0" modifies the new directories.

Comment: -1 because this is the wrong way to fix this problem. If QGIS wants to drop support for windows, then do it honestly. Don't do it by making it so darn hard to get windows versions to work. Support in every operating system for long filenames has been around for 20 years now. Suggesting that this needs to be fixed by going back to 8.3 is insane I think