# Qgis 2.2 how to fix bad epsg.wkt load

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I installed Qgis 2.2 this morning from the ubuntugis repository for ubuntu precise.  Qgis works great, except that all the common projections have been deleted.  So, I am a Little bit having a heart attack.

It Looks, from the install log, like what happened is this:

```
Synchronizing CRS database with GDAL/PROJ definitions.
Load srs db from: /usr/share/qgis/resources/srs.db
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
Loading epsg.wkt
0 WKTs loaded
CRS update (inserted:0 updated:0 deleted:3631 errors:0)
No CRS updates were necessary.
qgis-common (2.2.0-1~precise1) wird eingerichtet.
```

This log is printed if I remove qgis and just install qgis-providers.

apt-get install --reinstall qgis doesn't fix it.
Even worse, I did an apt-get remove purge and went back to the qgis.org debian main, which installed dufour.  Projections were still wiped, and I got the same install log from qgis-provider-commons.  So, I can't get functional qgis back at all.

Is there any dependency I should be reinstalling to make this all go away, or a way I can explicitly update the CRS lists?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are the first one using QGIS 2.2. This could be worth a bug report at http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues?set_filter=1

Comment: I did, although I am nervous about reporting a bug when I don't know why it happened.

Comment: Do you use ubuntugis or ubuntugis-unstable? I updated from 2.0 to 2.2 using ubuntugis-unstable without running into this issue.

Comment: Similar issues in previous version http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/predefined-coordinate-systems-missing-in-qgis-2

Comment: I used ubuntugis-unstable.  Same thing. My setup is not particularly wacky. I have grass and saga and gdal and that's about it.

Comment: Yes, the error is the same as the error experienced with 1.8.  But reinstalling did not help, nor did going back a version.  I feel like it must be a gdal saga grass clobber of some kind, but I don't know what

Comment: You might have run into the same problem as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87477/qgis-gisbase-specify-location which is strangely on Windows, not Ubuntu. I have not yet successfully upgraded my own Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Maybe... if I install, I run as root.  Root has no GDAL_DATA environment variable, and why should it, if we are reinstalling gdal with qgis?  but if the install script doesn't have that variable set right when it runs crssync, maybe it couldn't find epsg.wkt, with horrible results?

Comment: A missing variable could be the reason for the installation break.

Comment: Incidentally, I had Occasion today to do another full reinstall of qgis grass saga from ubuntu-unstable.  The Problem is still there.  I am hoping it will go away in Qgis 2.4.

Answer (score 3):

In order to fix corruption of the projection database, as I had in this case, copy srs.db from an unaffected installation.  This is the database where all projections are stored.  On Linux, this can be found under /usr/share/qgis/resources.  On windows, this will be under Osgeo4w/apps/qgis/resources.  It doesn't matter if the unaffected computer is windows and the affected computer is Linux.  The files are portable. if you copy the file over and restart qgis, the projections will be there.  This is not an answer to why the installation failed, but it is what will save it.